# How to use `typing.get_type_hints` with PEP585 in Python3.8?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to use `typing.get_type_hints` for a dataclass annotated with `list[str]`:

```py
# python3.8
from __future__ import annotations # Enable PEP585 for Python3.8
import typing
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: list[int]


print(typing.get_type_hints(Foo))
```

but this code raises an error:

```
File "foo.py", line 11, in <module>
  print(typing.get_type_hints(Foo))
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

This exception is raised because python3.8 doesn't support runtime `list[str]` evaluation.
Is there another way to use this function in python3.8?
Or, If I use PEP585 with python3.8, is it completely unable to take the type information?

Note:

- The error is not occurred in `list[str]` line, but in `typing.get_type_hints`.
- We can use `list[str]` annotation if `from __future__ import annotations` is declared.

Comment: Per [the PEP you reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) that is only available from Python 3.9, you'll need to use `List` from `typing`.

Comment: PEP585 says `list[str]` can be used if `from __future__ import annotations` is declared: Please read here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/#implementation

Comment: I edited my post to clarify the error is not occurred in `list[str]`, but in `get_type_hints`

Comment: Yes, but only because you're postponing evaluation of the annotations by enabling that future behaviour. When you actually evaluate them, in this case using `get_type_hints`, you need *runtime support*. It's exactly this runtime support that PEP 585 adds, which means you need 3.9 or higher.

Comment: That wording is misleading. The annotation itself won't raise an error, and mypy will understand it, but anything that tries to evaluate the delayed annotation (like `typing.get_type_hints`) will fail.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I understand Python3.8 doesn't support runtime evaluation of `list[str]`. So I want to know how to use `typing.get_type_hints` in this case.

Comment: I thinks this behavior of `typing.get_type_hints` is a bug because it is not documented at all.

Comment: You can't use it, because it needs to evaluate the annotations, which it can't without runtime support. It's not a bug, and is documented - https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints says strings will be evaluated by it.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another way to get type hint?

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider the following example, as dataclasses aren't relevant to this behaviour:

```
class Foo:
    bar: list[str]
```

In Python < 3.9, this leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "main.py", line 2, in Foo
    bar: list[str]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

If we add `from __future__ import annotations`, all that does (per [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)) is store the annotations as strings, for later evaluation:

> ...function and variable annotations will no longer be evaluated at
> definition time. Instead, a string form will be preserved in the
> respective `__annotations__` dictionary.

If we add that import, the class definition doesn't error out, and we can see what annotations get stored in their raw form in `__annotations__`:

```
>>> Foo.__annotations__
{'bar': 'list[str]'}
```

This is what [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) means when it says:

> Starting with Python 3.7, when `from __future__ import annotations` is
> used, function and variable annotations can parameterize standard
> collections directly.

Because the annotations are stored as strings, the fact that `list[str]` won't actually run in 3.7 and 3.8 isn't a problem. It does **not** mean that the standard collections themselves can be indexed this way, indeed it goes on to add:

> Usefulness of this syntax before PEP 585 is limited ... certain
> features of typing like type aliases or casting require putting types
> outside of annotations, in runtime context.

So when do we bring `'list[str]'` into a runtime context? What [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) does includes:

> ...forward references encoded as string literals are handled by
> evaluating them in `globals` and `locals` namespaces.

That's why the error in your example comes from `print(typing.get_type_hints(Foo))`, *not* the definition of the class - that's when the postponed evaluation occurs.

In short, there's no way to use `get_type_hints`, or anything else that evaluates the annotations, unless:

1. You use `typing.List` instead of the built-in `list`; or
2. You upgrade to at least Python 3.9.

In either case, there's no longer any need for the `__future__` import (unless other annotations need the postponed evaluation behaviour).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I'll convince myself to think `from __future__ ...` is just a "patch" so it leads some inconveniences like this...